# null pointer exception from Session

Tags: spring, session, gwt, spring-4-gwt

I'm using [`spring4gwt`](http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/) in my project.

I have the following login service implementation:

```
@Service("loginService")
public class LoginServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements LoginService {

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public UserBean checkUser(String userName, String password) throws Exception {

        HttpSession httpSession = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();

    }
}
```

When I call the `loginService.checkUser("test","test")` (In hosted mode), I get a NullPointerException, as `getThreadLocalRequest()` returns NULL instead of the actual session.

I didn't try in web mode yet.

Why would I get a null session? Does it have something to do with spring4gwt?

Comment: @Filburt : isn't GWT keyword relevent in the title ?

Comment: It's in the tags, so it's simply not necessary in the title.

Comment: what about the keyword `Session`? it's also in the tags.. Anyways..

Comment: It's not that keywords are *forbidden* in the title. If they are used in a sentence that makes a concise question it's absolutly okay to use tags in the title. Btw: Check out Google search results: SO titles are prefixed automagically with the most popular tag. On the questions list here, tag prefixes are just noise and should be avoided.

Comment: well in this case SO title is prefixed with the `Spring` tag which is less relevant than `GWT` tag for my question. The answer was more related to the spring4gwt then spring itself..

Comment: Meta reasoning on the matter: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190) ... and added spring4gwt tag.

Comment: @Filburt thank you. shouldn't the tag be spring4gwt without dashes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is because of `spring4gwt`, we need a different approch.

I found the solution here http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/issues/detail?id=2:

in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/your-url/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and instead of :

```
 HttpSession httpSession = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
```

Use :

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession httpSession = attr.getRequest().getSession();
```

Comment: Thank you heaps for posting your solution :) this helped me out a lot!